# Ambiguous complex analysis integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Studying for my complex analysis final and I came across this problem:

> Evaluate $\int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz$, where
>
> $$ f(z) = \frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)(z-4)} $$
>
> and $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve lying inside $\{ \mathrm{Re}(z) > 0 \}$
>   and not passing through $1$, $2$, and $4$. Does $f(z)$ have an
>   antiderivative in $\{ \mathrm{Re}(z)> 0\}$?

Where I'm struggling is that it is not stated whether $1$, $2$, or $4$ are in the interior of $\gamma$. If they do, then the computation is very simple using residue theory. If not, then the integral is simply zero, per a theorem that we learned a few weeks ago.

Could anyone offer advice on how to approach this problem?

Comment: You have given that $\gamma$ lies in the upper half plane $Re(z)>0$.

Comment: $\Re(z) > 0$ is the right half plane, not the upper half plane.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the orientation of $\gamma$ and on whether the points $1$, $2$ and $4$ are (or not) in the interior of $\gamma$, the result will be different since $$\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\frac1{2\pi\mathrm i}\,\left(\frac13\mathrm{ind}_\gamma(1)-\mathrm{ind}_\gamma(2)+\frac23\mathrm{ind}_\gamma(3)\right).$$
For example, if $\gamma$ is the circle centered at $\frac52$ with radius $1$ oriented clockwise, then $$\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\frac1{2\pi\mathrm i}\,\left(\frac13\cdot0-(-1)+\frac23(-1)\right)=\frac1{6\pi\mathrm i}.$$

> Does $f(z)$ have an antiderivative in $\{ \mathrm{Re}(z)> 0\}$?

If it has, what can you say about $\displaystyle\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz$ for every $\gamma$ included in this half plane?